# Python skipping iterator

Tags: python, iterator

I'm trying to build a 'skipper' in Python using iterators.

The idea is that given the following:

```
' '.join([str(i) for i in skippy([1,'a','b','b',2,1,1,1,'c','d','b'])
```

We get

```
1 b b 2 1 d b
```

As output. The rule being everytime we hit an integer x, we skip the *following* x items in the iterable.

So far I have:

```
def skippy(it):
    p = 0    
    for x in it:
        if type(x) == int:
           for x in range(x):
              p = next(it)
           yield p
```

And this doesn't work as expected, any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: How would you ever get output with integers in it? As soon as you hit an int, you should be skipping that many elements again.

Comment: @MorganThrapp: I think the idea is you yield that integer, but then skip the N *following* elements.

Comment: @BrenBarn is correct!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve with using a separate `p` and `x`.  You can just do this:

```
def skippy(it):
    it = iter(it)
    for x in it:
        if type(x) is int:
            yield x
            for skip in range(x):
                next(it)
        else:
            yield x

>>> ' '.join([str(i) for i in skippy(iter([1,'a','b','b',2,1,1,1,'c','d','b']))])
'1 b b 2 1 d b'
```

You need to call `iter` on the argument if you want to be able to pass a list in directly, because a list is an iterable, not an iterator, and you can only call `next` on an iterator.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to achieve, I was trying to create a pointer of sorts with p and x. I guess this is much simpler! Thank you

Comment: I was going to post nearly the same answer, except I dispensed with the `else` and put the `yield` before the type check (you yield on both branches of the if-statement).  That would make it shorter.

Comment: Note: The explicit loop with `next` calls would probably be done more efficiently (and without raising `StopIteration` in the generator, [which is a source of bugs and now deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-479-change-stopiteration-handling-inside-generators)), by using part of the consume pattern from the itertools recipes. Instead of the `for` loop with repeated `next` calls, do: `next(itertools.islice(it, x, x), None)` which doesn't `raise` `StopIteration` directly, allowing generator to exit safely. Also runs faster for long skips by pushing work to C layer.

Comment: @ShadowRanger:  You make a fair point about the implications of the naked `next(it)`, but in this case the problem can be solved with `next(it, None)`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: That ends up continuing to skip over and over even if the skip count takes you beyond the end of the list (`islice` will stop on the first `StopIteration`). In any event, the full consume pattern it optimizes further (for speed & code size; why generate unused `range` of `int`s?), and it's generally accepted as a Pythonic idiom (or at least, close enough; you might split it off into a separate method following the [`itertools` `consume` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) to improve the self-documenting/modular aspects of the code).

Answer (score 1):

You can skip (no pun intended) the yield and do basic operations:

```
def skippy(it):
  skip = 0
  answer = []
  for x in it:
    if skip>0:
      skip -= 1;
    elif type(x) == int:
      skip = x
      answer.append(str(x))
    else:
      answer.append(str(x))
  return ' '.join(answer)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own skipper iteration class and define the next function to do what you want like so

```
class Skippy:
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.l = l
        self.current = 0
        self.high = len(l)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.current >= self.high:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            current = self.l[self.current]
            self.current += 1
            if type(current) == int:
                self.current += self.l[self.current-1]
            return current

l = ' '.join([str(i) for i in Skippy([1,'a','b','b',2,1,1,1,'c','d','b'])])
print l

1 b b 2 1 d b
```

Comment: This works, but a generator function is simpler and better.  (See @BrenBarn's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33377559/1322401).)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I know but it's always good to know your options